# Why are Three.js Geometries losing precision with large numbers?

Tags: three.js, floating-point, precision

I'm trying to draw this hexagon in Three.js. If I use small numbers, it draws fine. But if I use big numbers (that seem to fit into a double without losing precision), Three.js seems to have issues drawing it precisely. I have demonstrated this in a [code pen here](https://codepen.io/bzuillsmith/pen/OdBgEz). The code of it is below. Notice if you change the `offsetX` and `offsetY` to be very large numbers, it does not draw the same. I don't quite understand why and was wondering if someone could shed some light on this for me. It seems like these numbers all fit within the double type...

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

const offsetX = 0;
const offsetY = 0;
// comment the previous two lines or following two lines to see the difference 
// const offsetX = 3031034;
// const offsetY = 4647776;

var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(offsetX-3,offsetX+3,offsetY-3,offsetY+3,1,100);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(400, 400);
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(offsetX + 1.039688, offsetY + 0.850723, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(offsetX + 0.913957, offsetY + 1.068813, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(offsetX + 0.661409, offsetY + 1.069356, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(offsetX + 0.534591, offsetY + 0.851991, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(offsetX + 0.660321, offsetY + 0.633721, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(offsetX + 0.91287, offsetY + 0.633178, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(offsetX + 1.039688, offsetY + 0.850723, 0));

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ linewidth: 1, color: 0x00ff00 });

var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
scene.add( line );

camera.position.z = 5;

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the numbers you show can be represented with sufficient precision in a `double` format to render the hexagon with no visible distortion, it appears WebGL does not use a `double` format throughout its operation.

[three.js uses WebGL](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-use-WebGL2), and [WebGL uses OpenGL ES](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/). Information about floating-point formats or arithmetic in the documentation for [WebGL](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Main_Page) and [OpenGL ES](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf) is spotty or missing. We can only informally infer the formats used from oblique references in the documentation and from the observed behavior.

Most likely, some component in the software is using the IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point format. In this format, the significand<sup>1</sup> has 24 bits.

With the offsets you show, such as 4,647,776, the exponent of the floating-point format must be set so the highest bit of the significand represents 4,194,304, which is 2<sup>22</sup>. Then the lowest bit is 2<sup>−1</sup>, or ½.

This means all the coordinates for the vertices of your hexagon, .661409, .851991, .633721, and so on, will be rounded to the nearest ½. Obviously this distorts the drawing. Tinkering with other values for the offsets shows effects consistent with 32-bit binary floating-point precision.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> A floating-point number consists of a sign bit *s*, a significand *f*, and an exponent *e*, and represents the value (−1)<sup>*s*</sup> • *f* • *b*<sup>*e*</sup>, where *b* is the base or radix of the format (2 for binary). The significand is also called the fraction portion of the floating-point representation, hence the *f* for significand.