# WebGL is rendering shapes wrong

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have some code that is supposed to take some parsed radar data, and render it on a Mapbox GL JS map with WebGL. I have gotten as far as being able to render the general radar shape onto a map, but the rendering is wrong. The shapes being drawn are not rectangles like they should be, but they are jerking around whenever the map is zoomed. Here are some gifs detailing the issues:

**Here is how it should be rendering:** (I am just using GeoJSON here, very slow loading time)

[image]

**Here is how it is actually rendering:** (disregard the color palette change)

[image]

As you can see, the WebGL version is very janky, and it is messing up the shapes on every zoom. What is going wrong here?

You can view a demo of this issue here: https://steepatticstairs.github.io/radar_rendering_tests/radar-demo.html Just zoom into the blue marker and you will see the issue. You can find the source code here: https://github.com/SteepAtticStairs/radar_rendering_tests but I will add a code snippet here for the sake of ease.

**HTML:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>QuadWeather Radar</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no,width=device-width' />
    <meta name="Description" content="View 3D radar for severe storms." />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/radarstyle.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="texturecolorbar" class="texturecolorbar"></canvas>
    <div id="map" class="mobilemap"></div>
    <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
      //x: azimuth
      //y: range
      //z: value
      attribute vec2 aPosition;
      attribute float aColor;
      uniform mat4 u_matrix;
      varying float color;

      void main() {
        color = aColor;
        gl_Position = u_matrix * vec4(aPosition.x,aPosition.y,0.0,1.0);
      }
    </script>
    <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
      precision mediump float;
      varying float color;
      uniform sampler2D u_texture;
      void main() {
        //gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,color/60.0,0.0,1.0);
        float calcolor = (color)/(70.0);
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture,vec2(min(max(calcolor,0.0),1.0),0.0));
        //gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      //$.getJSON('./data/radar/KAMA_sub.json', function(data) {
      //  console.log(data);
      //})
    </script>
    <script src="scripts/demo-radar-script.js"></script>
  </body>  
</html>
```

**MAIN JS:**

```js
function onload() {
  var settings = {};
  settings["lat"]=35.0;
  settings["lon"]=-101.72;
  settings["mlat"]=34.95;
  settings["mlon"]=-101.75;
  settings["rlat"]=35.2333;
  settings["rlon"]=-101.709;
  settings["phi"]=0.483395;
  settings["base"] = "../data/radar/test.json";


  //set up mapbox map
  mapboxgl.accessToken=
    "pk.eyJ1IjoicXVhZHdlYXRoZXIiLCJhIjoiY2pzZTI0cXFjMDEyMTQzbnQ2MXYxMzd2YSJ9.kHgQu2YL36SZUgpXMlfaFg";

  var map=window.map=new mapboxgl.Map({
    container:'map',
    attributionControl:false,
    zoom:3,
    maxZoom:25,
    minZoom:3,
  //overlaying custom made mapboxGL map
//    style: 'mapbox://styles/quadweather/cjsgo4h6905rg1fmcimx6j9dr'
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/bright-v9',
    antialias:true,
    zoom:9,
    center:[settings.mlon, settings.mlat],
    //pitch:70.,
    //bearing:315
  });
  map.addControl(new mapboxgl.AttributionControl(),'top-right');
  map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(),'top-left');

  new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat([settings.rlon, settings.rlat])
    .addTo(map)

  function createTexture(gl) {
    var colors = {"refc0":['rgba(59,59,59,1)', //0
          'rgba(59,59,59,1)', //10
          'rgba(0,151,189,1)', //20
          'rgba(21,166,2,1)',   //30
          'rgba(250,208,0,1)',  //40
          'rgba(240,124,18,1)', //50
          'rgba(214,18,0,1)', //60
          'rgba(201,92,255,1)', //70
        ]}
    var values = {"refc0":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
    var colors=colors["refc0"];
    var levs=values["refc0"];
    var colortcanvas=document.getElementById("texturecolorbar");
    colortcanvas.width=1200;
    colortcanvas.height=1;
    var ctxt = colortcanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctxt.clearRect(0,0,colortcanvas.width,colortcanvas.height); 
    var grdt=ctxt.createLinearGradient(0,0,1200,0);
    var cmax=70;
    var cmin=0;
    var clen=colors.length;

    for (var i=0;i<clen;++i) {
      grdt.addColorStop((levs[i]-cmin)/(cmax-cmin),colors[i]);
    }
    ctxt.fillStyle=grdt;
    ctxt.fillRect(0,0,1200,1);
    imagedata=ctxt.getImageData(0,0,1200,1);
    imagetexture=gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,imagetexture);
    pageState.imagetexture = imagetexture;
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,imagedata)
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  }

  map.on("load", function() {
    //map.addLayer(layer3d);
    myWorker.postMessage([settings["base"],settings["phi"],settings["rlat"],settings["rlon"]]);
  })

  //compile shaders
  var vertexSource = document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent;
  var fragmentSource = document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent;
  var masterGl;
  var layer = {
    id:"baseReflectivity",
    type:"custom",
    minzoom:0,
    maxzoom:18,

    onAdd: function(map,gl) {
      masterGl = gl;
      createTexture(gl);

      var ext = gl.getExtension('OES_element_index_uint');
      var vertexShader=gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
      gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexSource);
      gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
      var compilationLog = gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader);
      console.log('Shader compiler log: ' + compilationLog);
      var fragmentShader=gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
      gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentSource);
      gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
      var compilationLog = gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader);
      console.log('Shader compiler log: ' + compilationLog);
      this.program = gl.createProgram();
      gl.attachShader(this.program, vertexShader);
      gl.attachShader(this.program, fragmentShader);
      gl.linkProgram(this.program);
      this.matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, "u_matrix");
      this.positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, "aPosition");
      this.colorLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, "aColor");
      this.textureLocation=gl.getUniformLocation(this.program,"u_texture");

      //data buffers
      this.positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
      this.indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
      this.colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    },//end onAdd
    render: function(gl,matrix) {
      //console.log("render base");
      var ext = gl.getExtension('OES_element_index_uint');
      //use program
      gl.useProgram(this.program);
      //how to remove vertices from position buffer
      var size=2;
      var type=gl.FLOAT;
      var normalize=false;
      var stride=0;
      var offset=0;
      //calculate matrices
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.matrixLocation,false,matrix);
      gl.uniform1i(this.textureLocation,0);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,this.positionBuffer);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,pageState.positions,gl.STATIC_DRAW);
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.positionLocation);
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.positionLocation,size,type,normalize,stride,offset);
      
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,this.colorBuffer);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,pageState.colors,gl.STATIC_DRAW);
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.colorLocation);
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.colorLocation,1,type,normalize,stride,offset);

      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,pageState.imagetexture);
      gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,imagedata)
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

      var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
      var count = pageState.indices.length;
      gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, pageState.positions.length/2);

    }//end render
  }

  function dataStore() {
    return {
      positions:null,
      indices:null,
      colors:null
    }
  }

  var pageState = dataStore();

  var myWorker = new Worker('scripts/generateVerticesRadarDemo.js');
  myWorker.onmessage=function(oEvent) {
    var data = new Float32Array(oEvent.data.data);
    var indices = new Int32Array(oEvent.data.indices);
    var colors = new Float32Array(oEvent.data.colors);
    pageState.positions = data;
    pageState.indices = indices;
    pageState.colors = colors;
    map.addLayer(layer);
  }
}

window.onload = onload();
```

**JS TO GENERATE LAT/LNG COORDS**

```js
onmessage=function(oEvent) {
  var url = oEvent.data[0];

  //250/2
  var gateRes = 1;
  if (url == "../data/radar/KTLX_sub.json") {
    gateRes = 1000/2;
  }

  function radians(deg) {
    return (3.141592654/180.)*deg;
  }

  var radarLat = radians(oEvent.data[2]);
  var radarLon = radians(oEvent.data[3]);
  var inv = 180.0/3.141592654;
  var re = 6371000.0;
  var phi = radians(oEvent.data[1]);
  var h0 = 0.0;
  
  function calculatePosition(az, range) {
        var mathaz = radians(90.0 - az);
        var h = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(range,2.0)+Math.pow(((4./3.)*re+h0),2.0)+2.*range*((4./3.)*re+h0)*Math.sin(phi))-(4./3.)*re;
        var ca = Math.acos((Math.pow(range,2.0)-Math.pow(re,2.0)-Math.pow(re+h,2.0))/(-2.0*re*(re+h)));
        var xcart = (ca*re)*Math.cos(mathaz);
        var ycart = (ca*re)*Math.sin(mathaz);
        //convert to latitude longitude
        var rho = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xcart,2.0)+Math.pow(ycart,2.0));
        var c = rho/re;
        var lat = Math.asin(Math.cos(c)*Math.sin(radarLat)+(ycart*Math.sin(c)*Math.cos(radarLat))/(rho))*inv;
        lon = (radarLon + Math.atan((xcart*Math.sin(c))/(rho*Math.cos(radarLat)*Math.cos(c)-ycart*Math.sin(radarLat)*Math.sin(c))))*inv;

        //console.log(lat, lon)

        mx = (180.0 + lon)/360.0;
        my = (180. - (180. / 3.141592654 * Math.log(Math.tan(3.141592654 / 4. + lat * 3.141592654 / 360.)))) / 360.; 
        //console.log(mx,my);
        return {
          x:mx,
          y:my
        }

  }

  //function to process file
  function reqListener() {
    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    var azs = json.azimuths;
    var min = azs[0];
    var max = azs[azs.length-1];

    for (var key in json.radials) {
      if (key == "azimuths") continue;
      key = +key;
      var values = json.radials[key];
      var az = azs[key];
      var leftAz, rightAz, bottomR, topR;

      //case when first az
      if (key == 0) {
        //case when crossing 0
        leftAz = (min + 360 + max)/2;
        rightAz = (az+azs[key+1])/2;
      } else if (key == azs.length-1) {
        //case when crossing 0 the other way
        leftAz = (az + azs[key-1])/2;
        rightAz = (min+360+max)/2; 
      } else {
        //case when nothing to worry about
        leftAz = (az + azs[key-1])/2;
        rightAz = (az + azs[key+1])/2;
      }

      //loop through radar range gates
      for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
        bottomR = values[i]-gateRes;
        topR = values[i] + gateRes;

        var bl = calculatePosition(leftAz, bottomR);
        //console.log(bl, bl.x);
        var tl = calculatePosition(leftAz, topR);
        var br = calculatePosition(rightAz, bottomR);
        var tr = calculatePosition(rightAz, topR);

        output.push(
          bl.x,//leftAz,
          bl.y,//bottomR,

          tl.x,//leftAz,
          tl.y,//topR,

          br.x,//rightAz,
          br.y,//bottomR,
          br.x,//rightAz,
          br.y,//bottomR,

          tl.x,//leftAz,
          tl.y,//topR,
          tr.x,//rightAz,
          tr.y//topR
        )
        var colorVal = json.values[key][i];
        colors.push(colorVal, colorVal, colorVal, colorVal, colorVal, colorVal);
      }
      
    }
    var typedOutput = new Float32Array(output);
    var colorOutput = new Float32Array(colors);
    var indexOutput = new Int32Array(indices);
    postMessage({"data":typedOutput.buffer,"indices":indexOutput.buffer,"colors":colorOutput.buffer},[typedOutput.buffer,indexOutput.buffer,colorOutput.buffer]);
  }

  //get file from server
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
  oReq.open("GET", url);
  oReq.send();

  var output = [];
  //var maxUn = 467000;
  //var firstGate = 2125;
  //var startingAngle = 0.0;
  var indices = [];
  var colors = [];
}
```

Comment: You're going to do some more narrowing down of what your problem is. That's a lot of code to dump and hope someone can diagnose for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are Three.js Geometries losing precision with large numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54705002/why-are-three-js-geometries-losing-precision-with-large-numbers)

Comment: You're hitting floating point precision artifacts. In other words: your numbers should have less digits. Choose a different origin of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found an answer. I don't think it was an issue with WebGL, I think it was an issue with the data I was giving it. I simply had to multiply each radar gate value by 100:

```js
bottomR = values[i]*100 - gateRes;
topR = values[i]*100 + gateRes;
```

and I had to set the gate resolution to the scan radius of a WSR-88D radar (460 KM):

```js
var gateRes = 460;
```

This is very nuanced, so if anybody comes across this exact problem, I hopes this helps you, but probably not.